# Create new mail address with postfix

Tags: postfix

I need to create a new mail address with postfix.

The problem is I joined a company and I am now in charge of the administration of the servers (but I am just a dev not an adminsys...), so I need to deal with a server architecture already in place but not documented and the guy who setup everything cannot be contacted.

So postfix is already in place and configured, it works fine with the mail addresses already set, and apparently postfix uses a postgrsql database but I have no information about the configuration of postfix and how it uses this DB.

I already have ssh access to the server and I have a unix account on it, how can I create a mail address for my account ?

Comment: if it is anything like postfix+mysql everything is managed via db entries.  can you get into the postgresql db and look at the tables, etc? Looking in /etc/postfix you should see the configuration files which will have postgres username/password and hostname in it, as well as the actual query for that particular lookup (ie, users, domain, whtaever).  here's a guide to similar configuration but using mysql - it may help you decide where to look and what to look for - https://workaround.org/ispmail/jessie

Answer (score 0):

I will try to do some guessing here:
Often postfix with database is used with maps. Files where you configure how a mailbox/alias etc can be fetched from database. Try to look into main.cf file or take a shot whit similar command like `grep maps main.cf | egrep -v "^#"`. In my case you will find:

```
grep maps main.cf | egrep -v "^#"
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
smtp_sasl_password_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/smtp_auth.cf
```

This should point you to the right direction. Inside thise files you will find something like:

```
user = <DB_USERNAME>
password = <DB_PASSWORD>
hosts = <DB_ADDRESS>
dbname = <DATABASE_NAME>
query = SELECT 1 FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%s'
```

Knowing this you will know where to find a database server what database/schema it is using, what are credentials and data structure.
Then, probably all you have to do is to make an insert to database.

But, as I said earlier, I'm guessing here.

Comment: I searched in main.cf (there also was dynamicmaps.cf and master.cf files) but didn't find anything, just "alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases".
I accessed the DB, there was a DB mail with 3 tables, domain, users and aliases. In the users table it is just mail, password (sha 512 hash), and maildir, the maildir looks like a directory almost always in the form 'mailaddress@domain.com/' but such none of the directories listed exist on the server. It seems it is not the entries in the DB that define the mail addresses but postfix that fill the DB when adding a user from the command